# Timeout error with Nightwatch-Cucumber and Nightwatch

Tags: javascript, node.js, cucumber, nightwatch.js, cucumberjs

**Current behavior**
I work with Nightwatch-Cucumber and the PageObject Pattern and I get an unexprected `Error: function timed out after 60000 milliseconds`.

**Expected/desired behavior**
All Nightwatch-Cucumber checks (like visibility checks) have to fail and no timeout problem has to occur.

**Reproduction of the problem**
As pre-conditions I set the default timeout (60 seconds) globally in timeout.js:

```
const {defineSupportCode} = require('cucumber');

defineSupportCode(({setDefaultTimeout}) => {
  setDefaultTimeout(60 * 1000);
});
```

...and I set the `waitForConditionTimeout` and `waitForConditionPollInterval` for Nightwatch in `nightwatch.conf.js`:

```
  test_settings: {
    default: {
      globals : {
        "waitForConditionTimeout": 30000,
        "waitForConditionPollInterval": 500
      },
```

Now I have a Cucumber test that has to fail. So, I want to test the right behaviour of the testframework:

```
Feature: only a test feature

  Scenario: only a test Scenario
    #first step should pass
    Given a user is on a details page with id "123"
    #second step should fail
    Then user is on the first page of the booking funnel
```

And here are the two step definitions:

```
const {client} = require('nightwatch-cucumber');
const {defineSupportCode} = require('cucumber');

const detailsPage = client.page.detailsPageView();
const bookingPage = client.page.bookingStepOnePageView();

defineSupportCode(({Given, When, Then}) => {

  Given(/^a user is on a details page with id "([^"]*)"$/, (id) => {
    return detailsPage.openUrlWithId(client, id);
  });

  Then(/^user is on the first page of the booking funnel$/, () => {
    return bookingPage.checkFirstStepOfBookingFunnel(client);
  });
});
```

And here is the page object function for first cucumber step (`detailsPageView.js`):

```
module.exports = {
  elements: {},
  commands: [{
    openUrlWithId(client, id) {
      return client
        .url('http://test.com?id=' + id);
    }
  }]
};
```

...and the page object function for second cucumber step (`bookingStepOnePageView`):

```
const offerSummary = 'div[id="offerSummary"]';

module.exports = {
  elements: {},
  commands: [{
    checkFirstStepOfBookingFunnel(client) {
      client.expect.element(offerSummary).to.be.visible.after();
      return client;
    },
  }]
};
```

Now if I will run my test I expect that the second cucumber step will fail, because the first page of booking funnel is not loaded and present. So, the visibility check in booking page object function `client.expect.element(offerSummary).to.be.visible.after();` has to fail. Now I expect that the defined `"waitForConditionTimeout":30000` in `nightwatch.conf.js` will use in that case and the visibility check will fail after 30 seconds, but I get a timeout error after 60 seconds how it is defined in `timeout.js` with `setDefaultTimeout(60*1000)`.

And additionally my test run (test process via `nightwatch --env chrome`) doesn't end and the browser window doesn't close. So I have to end the run (process) manually with `ctrl + c`.

Here you can see the output:

```
grme:e2e-web-tests GRme$ npm run test-chrome

> e2e-web-tests@0.0.2 test-chrome /Users/GRme/projects/myProject/e2e-web-tests
> nightwatch --env chrome

Starting selenium server... started - PID:  29642
Feature: only a test feature

  @run
  Scenario: only a test Scenario
  ✔ Given a user is on a details page with id "123"
  ✖ Then user is on the first page of the booking funnel

Failures:

1) Scenario: only a test Scenario - features/testFeature.feature:4
   Step: Then user is on the first page of the booking funnel - features/testFeature.feature:6
   Step Definition: features/step_definitions/bookingFunnelStepDefinition.js:33
   Message:
     Error: function timed out after 60000 milliseconds
         at Timeout._onTimeout (/Users/GRme/projects/myProject/e2e-web-tests/node_modules/cucumber/lib/user_code_runner.js:91:22)
         at ontimeout (timers.js:488:11)
         at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
         at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:283:5)

1 scenario (1 failed)
2 steps (1 failed, 1 passed)
1m09.648s
^C
grme:e2e-web-tests GRme$
```

On last line you can see the `^C` as my manually stopped test process.

Especially when I want to execute a test suite with maybe two cucumber tests. The first test is the one I explained and the second is a one where I expect a `pass`. In this case both tests will fail for me, because in the second test the visibility check of the first test (`client.expect.element(offerSummary).to.be.visible.after();`) will fail and I don't know why.

This is my console output for both tests (the second one has to pass!):

```
grme:e2e-web-tests GRme$ npm run test-chrome

> e2e-web-tests@0.0.2 test-chrome /Users/GRme/projects/myProject/e2e-web-tests
> nightwatch --env chrome

Starting selenium server... started - PID:  29691
Feature: only a test feature

  @run
  Scenario: only a test Scenario
  ✔ Given a user is on a details page with id "123"
  ✖ Then user is on the first page of the booking funnel

  @run
  Scenario: only a test Scenario 2
  ✖ Given a user is on a details page with id "123"

Failures:

1) Scenario: only a test Scenario - features/testFeature.feature:4
   Step: Then user is on the first page of the booking funnel - features/testFeature.feature:6
   Step Definition: features/step_definitions/bookingFunnelStepDefinition.js:33
   Message:
     Error: function timed out after 60000 milliseconds
         at Timeout._onTimeout (/Users/GRme/projects/myProject/e2e-web-tests/node_modules/cucumber/lib/user_code_runner.js:91:22)
         at ontimeout (timers.js:488:11)
         at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
         at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:283:5)

2) Scenario: only a test Scenario 2 - features/testFeature.feature:9
   Step: Given a user is on a details page with id "123" - features/testFeature.feature:10
   Step Definition: features/step_definitions/detailStepDefinition.js:12
   Message:
     Expected element <div[id="offerSummary"]> to be visible - element was not found - Expected "visible" but got: "not found"
         at Page.checkFirstStepOfBookingFunnel (/Users/GRme/projects/myProject/e2e-web-tests/pageobjects/bookingStepOnePageView.js:49:21)
         at World.Then (/Users/GRme/projects/myProject/e2e-web-tests/features/step_definitions/bookingFunnelStepDefinition.js:34:24)

2 scenarios (2 failed)
3 steps (2 failed, 1 passed)
1m11.448s
^C
grme:e2e-web-tests GRme$
```

Maybe my tests will fail and the worst thing is that my test process doesn't end or keep going on with the next cucumber tests.

**So, how can I solve the timeout problem with `Nightwatch` and `Nightwatch-Cucumber`?**

**My environment:**

```
Mac OS X 10.12.5
Chrome Browser 59.0.3071.115
npm 5.0.4
cucumber@2.3.1
nightwatch@0.9.16
nightwatch-cucumber@7.1.10
v8.0.0
```

I hope you can help me :)

Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried debugging a little bit more. Maybe it's a bug with the `Expect`?

I set my global timeout to 20 seconds:

```
const {defineSupportCode} = require('cucumber');

defineSupportCode(({setDefaultTimeout}) => {
  setDefaultTimeout(20 * 1000);
});
```

And now I have a following `Expect` check:

`client.expect.element(myElement).text.to.contain(myText).after(10000);`

In my case `myElement` can not be found in DOM to produce an error. But now I get the error message `Error: function timed out after 20000 milliseconds`, but I exprect that the test fails after 10 seconds because the element `myElement` can not be found in DOM.

After that I tried to replace the Expect API method with Nightwatch Command:

```
client
  .waitForElementVisible(arrivalDepartureDate, 10000)
  .assert.containsText(myElement, myText);
```

And now I get the right error after 10 seconds `ERROR: Unable to locate element: ".Grid__colM3___EyfpA" using: css selector`.

It's a workaround to forgo `Expect`, in my case now I have two commands to check element and their text. With `Expect` I can do it both in one line command.